# GAM: Why are confidence bands equal to zero when predicted value is zero?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, linear-model, generalized-additive-model, splines

This seems to be an easy question but I still can't answer it after researching for a few hours, so I hope someone can help me:

I'm calculating generalized additive regression models using R. Some of the effects seem to be linear. What I'm wondering about are their confidence bands: They look linear as well and when the effect is close to zero, also the confidence bands hit the zero from both sides (here using *plot.gam()*):

[image: Linear confidence band]

I figured out that the dotted line can be manually calculated and drawn using ggplot by *$model\$fit \pm model\$se$*. My questions:

1. How can this be interpreted?
2. Is the effect of zero really so stable for $x\approx450$?
3. Are those even the confidence bands?

Also while researching I found another person getting a curved confidence band for a linear effect using the visreg-package:

[image: Curved confidence band]

4. If the linear lines of the first picture are confidence bands, what is this?
5. Can the curved lines be calculated given *plot.gam()* or manually and if yes, with which values of the model?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the bands in the plots of the smooths don't include the uncertainty in the model intercept, and occur because of the sum-to-zero constraint applied to each smooth. Technically the effect being shown with the sum-to-zero constraint has to pass through 0 and where it passes through zero you get a zero width credible interval. Of course this is nonsense, but it's a function of how the smooths are actually produced.

You can include the uncertainty in the intercept in these plots by using `seWithMean = TRUE` in the `plot()` call. This produces plots where we assume that the uncertainty in the model constant term (the intercept) is carried only by the smooth being shown; if you have several smooths in the model, the plots are generated as if each smooth in turn were carrying the uncertainty from the model intercept.

If you use the `seWithMean` option then the credible intervals shown will be slightly curved.